# Undo user delation and removal of his project

Tags: gitlab, undo

In our own Gitlab server, I accidentally removed the default admin, and the previous repo created by this default admin, is also gone.

How to recover the missing repo?

Comment: Are they ordinary repos? If so, there must be an up-to-date clone somewhere.

Comment: @merlin2011, thanks for the suggestion. Shall do that as the last resort, :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following merlin2011's suggestion, I finally cloned my local copy to the gitlab server:

```
git remote -v  // list all remote repo
git add repo 192.168.1.xxx //our local git server
git push -u repo master
git remote remove repo
git add origin 192.168.1.xxx
```